# Do the characteristic vibrational modes of a material define how much will a material heat up upon radiation excitation?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, phonons, raman-spectroscopy

Do, and if yes how, does the intensity and energy of the Raman modes of a material make it to heat more by radiation excitation.

I see phonons and vibrations of the lattice as heat, but maybe I'm misinterpreting.

If that's true I'd assume that the higher the number of vibrational modes, their characteristic energy and intensity, the higher the ability of the material to heat.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic modes can be excited by photons whose energy matches these modes.  However, heating mechanisms are dependent on several other parameters, not the least of which is the surface shape.  Take a look at the literature on black-body cavities and on ultra-dark roughened surfaces for some info on how to maximize radiative absorption.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really an answer to my question. From all the factors that influence the heating of a material, I am trying to understand the contribuition of its characteristic phonons.